# Java Generics incompatable types when cast to the generic type

Tags: java, generics, casting, abstract-class

I have a abstract class which looks like this

```
public abstract class VehicleValidator< E extends Vehicle, C extends Config>  implements Validator< E , C  > {

@Override
public List<ValidationError<? extends Vehicle<E, C>>> validateBidElement(E vehicle, C configuration) {
    final List<ValidationError<? extends vehicle<E, C>>> errors = new ArrayList<>();
   //some logic to create the error
        errors.add(new ValidationError<>("VehicleValidator.InvalidPattern", VehicleValidator.class, ValidationError.Severity.ERROR));
   return errors;
}
```

The ValidationError class looks like below

```
public class ValidationError<T extends Validator> {

public enum Severity {
    WARNING,
    ERROR
}

String errorId;
Class<T> validatorClass;
Severity severity;}
```

The above give me an error

```
 Required type:
ValidationError
<? extends VehicleValidator<E, C>>
Provided:
ValidationError
<VehicleValidator>
```

What I understand is for creating the ValidationError, the second param  Class validatorClass, which means any class that extends Validator. My abstract class VehicleValidator implements Validator< E , C  >. So why am I asked to cast the parameter.

Comment: Why do you need the `T extends Validator` in the first place? The `validatorClass` field could just have the type `Class<?>`. The generics makes no sense here IMO

Comment: I have some logic inside the method, which I did not include